# How to explain to perforce-jam build system which compiler (gcc) it should use

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, arm

I try to make "hello world - project" using

- Jam (perforce) build system
- C++
- Linux
- arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc *compiller*

**helloworld-perforce-jam.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int args, char* argv[])
{

    printf("\n\n\nHello World from HELLOWORLD-PERFORCE-JAM!!!\n\n\n\n");
    return 0; 
}
```

**Jamfile**

```
Echo $(CC) ;
Main helloworld-perforce-jam : helloworld-perforce-jam.cpp ;
```

There are no blockers if I will use arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc directly without Jam-build system like:

```
ygyerts@ygyerts:$ /home/user/full_path/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc helloworld-perforce-jam.cpp
```

There is one executable for ARM architecture will be created.

There are no blockers if I use default gcc (defined by Jam), example:

```
ygyerts@ygyerts:$ jam
cc 
...found 66 target(s)...
...updating 1 target(s)...
Link helloworld-perforce-jam 
Chmod1 helloworld-perforce-jam 
...updated 1 target(s)...
```

There is one executable for !!!**x86 architecture**!!! will be created.

But the idea is to use custom gcc compiler (/home/user/full_path/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc). And this is a blocker, I do not know how...

I've try to play with parameters of jam executable like follow:

```
ygyerts@ygyerts:$ jam -s CC=/home/user/full_path/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc
/home/user/full_path/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc
...found 66 target(s)...
...updating 2 target(s)...
C++ helloworld-perforce-jam.o 
Link helloworld-perforce-jam 
helloworld-perforce-jam.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

/home/ygyerts/TOOLING/TeamCity/TeamCity-9.1.7/buildAgent/work/e58af29ade3fd40c/fsl-community-bsp/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -o helloworld-perforce-jam  helloworld-perforce-jam.o   

...failed Link helloworld-perforce-jam ...
...failed updating 1 target(s)...
...updated 1 target(s)...
```

Please help me to understand how to set all required environment to build helloworld with **arm-linux** architecture, not with **x86_64-linux**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you've set the path to the C compiler, but the C++ compiler (which is usually also the linker)

Try: `jam -sCC=/home/user/full_path/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -sC++=/home/user/full_path/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc`

You might also want to add the "-dx" debug flag, which will show you what commands jam is actually executing.

If you're feeling brave, check out the Perforce Jamrules (there's a rule named SetCommonCompiler which helps setup cross compilers):
 https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/projects/perforce_software-p4/files/2016-1/Jamrules

There are configurations in there for building on a wide range of platforms, with the appropriate compiler flags, but it's not for the faint-hearted.

Comment: Thank you vary math it works with next commands:

`export PATH="/home/ygyerts/TOOLING/TeamCity/TeamCity-9.1.7/buildAgent/work/e58af29ade3fd40c/fsl-community-bsp/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi:$PATH"`
 
`jam -sCC="arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -mfloat-abi=hard" -sC++="arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -mfloat-abi=hard"`